# what is used of nonce and timestamp in HMAC authentication

Tags: api, security, hmac

I am using HMAC authentication to secure API. I have read that nonce and timestamps can be used to prevent replay attack.

But my question is attacker can modified the nonce and timestamp to current time and resend the API call again then how HMAC will prevent replay attack??

Thanks,

Comment: 1) the server should reject timestamps that deviate too much from the current time. 2) the server should reject nonces that have already been used (within a certain period of time)

Comment: But what if an attacker modified timestamps to current server time and generates nonces that have not already been used ??

Comment: if the attacker modifies these fields, the signature will change (a different hash will be produced) thus making the server reject the request. Note that the timestamp and nonce must be included in the hashed payload for this.

Comment: @Bor - Thanks, i got the answer to my question.

Comment: @Bor - if i am not including nonce and timestamp in url and my url is using ssl (Secure connection) then will there be any chance of replay attack??

Comment: Yes, a replay attack by a malicious user of your application. They could store and replay a request much later when they are no longer an authorised user of your application and execute actions or read data. SSL/TLS only protects the connection from man-in-the-middle or eavesdroppers, it doesn't protect it from malicious users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time stamp in hMAC authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150187/time-stamp-in-hmac-authentication)